# In ES6, can I use Arrow functions as short hand for .bind(this, ...) with arguments?

Tags: javascript, parameters, ecmascript-6, arrow-functions

Though I know arrow functions aren't intended to be a complete replacement of it, can I use an arrow function as shorthand for this syntax:

```
(function(a, b) { ... }).bind(this, obj.a, obj.b)
```

I understand that it is possible to [give arrow functions default values](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions), but I don't know if default values can be variables:

```
(a = obj.a, b = obj.b) => { ... }
```

I tried this and NodeJS barked at me (unexpected token =), so I'm wondering, what is the right way to do this?

Here is a sample use case (with my ... "creative" syntax):

```
var obj = {a: 10, b: 'String'};
functionReturningAPromise()
    .then((a = obj.a, b = obj.b) => this.someFunction(a + b));
```

versus:

```
var obj = {a: 10, b: 'String'};
functionReturningAPromise()
    .then((function(a, b) { return this.someFunction(a + b); }).bind(this, obj.a, obj.b));
```

Comment: What do you do with result? `(a = obj.a, b = obj.b) => { ... }` expression creates a function. What next? Btw, `bind` partially applies a function, and default parameters can be re-set, so they have different semantics.

Comment: completely ignoring the question of whether it works, why would this be a good idea? Your code has no guarantee that `obj.a` and `obj.b` won't change *while running your arrow function*, so this is an incredibly dangerous code construction. And on an "asking a good question" note, your title does not reflect the actual question you're asking, you probably want to review that.

Comment: @zerkms I have added a use case for why I would want to do this. It boils down to "I want to press less keys." Whether or not it's a good idea is _also_ something I am interested in, but SO tends not to be the place for what should and should not be.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans "incredibly dangerous code construction" --- unless it's not. That's what **variables** were invented for - to be able to change.

Comment: Your code is a correct ES2015 syntax. It's not obvious though why you did not do `() => this.someFunction(obj.a, obj.b)` instead

Comment: @zerkms That is good to know (even though I can't quite get NodeJS to like it) - more importantly, is this the _correct_ way to do it? Will `.bind(this, obj.a, obj.b)` behave like `(a = obj.a, b = obj.b) => `?

Comment: It depends on how the function will be called. If any parameter will be passed - the calls would lead to different results.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans to be clear, the sample arrow function code that I gave as an example in my post was an illustration of the best way I knew to do something like this. I am not asking if it would work, I can test that myself by putting it in an interpreter. As I ask in my post, _what is the right way to do this?_ What I want to know (as the title states) is can an arrow function syntactically do what `.bind(this, ...)` can do?

Comment: No, `bind` seta the arguments' valurea and they cannot be overwritten when the function is called. Default values can be overwritten when the function is called.

Comment: Side note, you can use `({a, b} = {}) => {...}`, since you said you wanted press less keys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem I essentially was trying to solve was the classic "use `setTimeout` to call a function with parameters" problem, except with arrow functions. *(But more generally, with any function, not just `setTimeout`.)*

There are three nearly identical ways to solve this (the last one with arrow functions):

### Using closures

```
var self = this;
functionThatReturnsAPromise()
    .then((function() { return self.someFunction(obj.a + obj.b); }));
```

It works, but I would explicitly have to set `this` to some other variable, like self.

### Using bind

```
functionThatReturnsAPromise()
    .then((function(a, b) { return this.someFunction(a + b); }).bind(this, obj.a, obj.b));
```

A little better than the first, since I can just use `this` without any hackery, but it gets quite a bit verbose.

### Using ES6 arrow functions

```
functionThatReturnsAPromise()
    .then(() => this.someFunction(obj.a + obj.b));
```

A ha! Very concise. I no longer have to specify `this`, and I don't have to pass in any parameters either, since the arrow function preserves the parent closures stack frame. When the arrow function gets executed, it knows what `obj.a` and `obj.b` refer to. I have now achieved `bind` functionality with ES6 arrow function syntax.

Comment: What I originally failed to understand about ES6 syntax was that if I wanted to reference parameters from the *current* stack frame in *another* function, arrow functions do this automatically without the requirement of passing in parameters.

Answer (score 2):

> In ES6, can I use arrow functions as shorthand for `.bind(this, …)` with arguments?

The short answer is no, not in the way you seem to envision.

> I understand that it is possible to give arrow functions default values, but I don't know if default values can be variables:

I guess you mean "give arrow function's **parameters** default values". Of course they can be variables or any expression. But this is not limited to arrow functions--any function can have default parameter values.

You are confusing binding parameters--which burns in their value in advance--with default parameters, which fill in missing parameters at invocation time. That is the fundamental difference between your two code fragments.

Comment: `node does not support parameter defaults at the moment` Thanks. It is really hard on the web to find "Is X _not_ supported?" since all you get is "W, Y and Z _are_ supported."